# localhost.run wordpress ssh tunneling

Tags: wordpress, ssh-tunnel, tunneling

I need to show a preview of a wordpress project to a client. I want to setup a tunnel to expose the macOS apache server instance. In past I was using ngrok but with wordpress it requires some configuration and I don't want to waste time in plugins installation ecc. 
I've tried with Serveo, but it seems to be offline at the moment, after a little bit of research I've found localhost.run that offer the same service of Serveo. 
How I can find the actual port of the embed apache server of my macOS and how I will expose wordpress without plugins installation?
I've tried with this command

`ssh -R 80:localhost:8080 ssh.localhost.run`

but it will give an error when I open the tunneling url:

> Something went wrong opening the port forward, check your SSH command output for clues!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the Apache "httpd.conf" to

Listen 8080 and 
ServerName localhost:8080